# Creating default object from empty value on update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I realize this question has been asked several times on this forum, but none of the solutions given has resolved my particular issue.
I get the above error when trying to update my DB.
Here is a snippet of my code

1. I have tried adding findorfail on my request by id
   `$service=Service::findorfail($request->input('id'));`

This returns a 404 page.

**ServiceController.php**

```
    public function updateService(Request $request){
        // return $request->all();
        $this->validate($request, ['serviceTitle'=> 'required',
            'serviceSubTitle'=> 'required',
            'description'=> 'required',
            'slug' => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:services',
            'serviceImage'=>'image|nullable|max:1999']);
            $service=Service::find($request->input('id'));
            $service->title =$request->input('serviceTitle');
            $service->sub_title =$request->input('serviceSubTitle');
            $service->slug =$request->input('slug');
            $service->description =$request->input('description');
            
        if($request->hasFile('serviceImage')) {
            //1 : get filename with ext
            $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('serviceImage')->getClientOriginalName();
    
            //2 : get just file name
            $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    
            //3 : get just extension
            $extension = $request->file('serviceImage')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
            //4: filename to store
            $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //upload image
            $path =$request->file('serviceImage')->storeAs('public/serviceImage', $fileNameToStore);
            $old_image =Service::find($request->input('id'));
    
            if($old_image!='noimage.jpg') {
                Storage::delete('public/serviceImage/'.$old_image->image);
            }
            $service->image =$fileNameToStore;
        }
        $service->update();
        return redirect('/services')->with('status', 'The '.$service->title.' Service has been updated successfully');
    }
```

The error log tells me the error is on this specific line:

`$service->title =$request->input('serviceTitle');`

Thank you for time and assistance.

Comment: and what's the error?

Comment: Can you please share the route that you have defined.

Comment: There are typos in `$service=Service::findorfail($request->input('id'));`. Did you tried with `$service=Service::findOrFail($request->input('id'));` ?